# Sidekiq Unique Jobs for different workers

Tags: sidekiq

How do you ensure uniqueness on Sidekiq using Sidekiq Unique Jobs when the uniqueness has to be for two workers with different names?

The docs show that you can have control on uniqueness based on the arguments of the worker, but not on the class itself: https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs#finer-control-over-uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new unique worker that instantiate those two workers itself.